# What is Grace period in Apple In App Purchase? How to configure it in Apple store connect?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

I am working on In App Purchase, I am aware of creating and configuring In App Purchases , I have also set trial period but don't have any idea about Grace period. Please help on grace period configuration in Apple store connect. Thanks in advance